# When I uploaded my laravel project to the live server only home page is working and other controller and view not working

Tags: laravel

My laravel project working properly in local server.But when I upload in the live server only home page working and other controller and view does not working.
[When I click cart button then showing me this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oznO.png)

Comment: It looks like that view file isn't on your server. Can you find it? Are the permissions correct?

Comment: now its working.....thanks